# Checkbox in React Calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, react-hooks, calculator

I am building calculator with couple of different inputs and one of them is also checkbox.

The main idea is that by default checkbox is checked, but user can uncheck it and of course the final value will change (it will minus the checkbox value)

Example:

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);

 <FormControl
              aria-label="value1"
              onChange={(event) =>
              setValue1(event.target.value)
              }
              placeholder={value1}
 />
 <FormControl
              aria-label="value2"
              onChange={(event) =>
              setValue1(event.target.value)
              }
              placeholder={value2}
 />
```

### The checkbox value comes from multiplication value1 * value2

```
const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        setCheckbox(value1 * value2);
    }, [ value1 ,value2 ]);
```

Now I am not sure how to handle this in input, this is what I tried:

```
<Form.Check
           checked={checkbox}
           onCheck={() => setCheckbox(!checkbox)}
/>
```

**The output from this is:**

1. By default the checkbox is UNCHECKED
2. When value1 and value2 is set the checkbox gets suddenly checked
3. When I try to uncheck the box - it won't allow me to do it

**Expected output:**

1. Checkbox is checked by default and has the value 0 by default, and when **value1** and **value2** is set, the checkbox gets the value of multiplication these two values
2. User is allowed to uncheck the box and final value coming from `value1 * value2 + checkbox` will get updated minus checkbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this you have to use the properties `checked` and `value` of the checkbox event.

You need to have 2 different states for the above.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(0);
```

Now your Form check should look like this,

```
<Form.Check
  checked={checked}
  value={checkboxValue}
  onCheck={(event) => setChecked(event.target.checked)}
/>
```

Your, `useEffect` block still remains the same ( just change `setCheckbox` to `setCheckboxValue` ) and any changes in `value1` and `value2` should automatically reflect in the value for checkbox.

For updating the final value when checkbox is unchecked, you can have another `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!checked) {
    setCheckboxValue(checkboxValue - value1 * value2);
  }
}, [checked])
```

Comment: Thank you @Saurish, now it is checked by default and I am able to uncheck it, but the final value stays the same - value1 * value2 + checkbox = finalValue, when checkbox is unchecked the finalValue should minus the checkbox value.

Comment: @Eliot Updated my answer in order to handle the case.

Comment: That helped, even though I had to customise it a bit - no second useEffect needed - I used it in first useEffect and I had to do `else {setCheckboxValue(0)`, otherwise it wouldn't work, also it should be `if(checked)` instead `if(!checked)`, thank you for leading me to right track!

Comment: @Eliot Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I don't understand the unchecking part. Please explain

```js
const App = () => {
  const [val1, setVal1] = React.useState(0);
  const [val2, setVal2] = React.useState(0);
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
  const [label, setLabel] = React.useState('0');
  React.useEffect(() => setLabel(Number(val1) * Number(val2)), [val1, val2])
  return <div>
    <input placeholder="val1" type="number" value={val1} onChange={e => setVal1(e.target.value)} />
    <input placeholder="val2" type="number" value={val2} onChange={e => setVal2(e.target.value)} />
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={e => setChecked(e.target.checked)} />
    <label for="checkbox">{label}</label>
  </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
```

Comment: Explanation: `value1 * value2 + checkbox = finalValue`, when checkbox is unchecked the finalValue should minus the checkbox value so finalValue will be only value1 * value2, when checkbox is checked again the value will be updated + checkbox.

Comment: so basically finalValue = 2*value1*value2 ?